# Django signals and proxy models

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

From what I tested, if I have a model (`Vehicle`) and 2 proxy models (`Car` and `Bike`, proxies of `Vehicle`) and I want to trigger a `post_save` signal, the signal will be triggered only by the save operation on the `Vehicle` model. I was expecting the signal to be triggered by the save operation also for `Car` and `Bike` because it's the same db table.

Does anyone knows where I can find an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: could you add the **models**  ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `add the models`.

Comment: models.py where you have the **Vehicle** , **Bike** and **Car** classes